# How to Split List of Strings of Unknown Length

Tags: list, python-3.x

Say you have a list you're not sure the length of like:

```
li1 = [Jan 1', 'Jan 2', 'Jan 3', 'Jan 4', 'Jan 5', 'Jan 6', 'Jan 7', 'Jan 8', 'Jan 9', 'Jan 10', 'Jan 11', 'Jan 12', 'Jan 13', 'Jan 14', 'Jan 15', 'Jan 16', 'Jan 17', 'Jan 18', 'Jan 19', 'Jan 20', 'Jan 21', 'Jan 22', 'Jan 23', 'Jan 24', 'Jan 25', 'Jan 26', 'Jan 27', 'Jan 28', 'Jan 29', 'Jan 30', 'Jan 31', 'Feb 1', 'Feb 2', 'Feb 3', 'Feb 4', 'Feb 5', 'Feb 6', 'Feb 7', 'Feb 8', 'Feb 9', 'Feb 10', 'Feb 11', 'Feb 12', 'Feb 13', 'Feb 14']
```

How can you split this so

```
a = [(first half of li1)]
b = [(second half of li1)]
```

Ive tried

```
a = [:len(li1)/2]
b = [len(li1)/2:]
```

And

```
a = li1[:len(li1)/2]
b = li1[len(li1)/2:]
```

And I get errors for both. My teacher mentioned something about indexing but didn't do a very good job of explaining4 it

Comment: Maybe just use `//` rather than `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You are not providing the list you want to slice (`a = [:len(li1)/2]`),

and
(2) in Python 3 `/` returns a float which can't be used as list indicies. You should use `//` instead.

So a working example would be:

```
a = li1[:len(li1) // 2]
b = li1[len(li1) // 2:]
```